# Uncertainty of a weighted mean of uncertain observations

Tags: mean, uncertainty, error-propagation

I have measured $x_i$, $i=1\ldots N$ with independent uncertainties $\sigma_i$.

I have calculated the weighted mean $\bar x$ with

$\bar x = \dfrac{\sum_i \dfrac{1}{\sigma_i} x_i }{ \sum_i \dfrac{1}{\sigma_i} }.$

What is the uncertainty of $\bar x$?

Comment: What quantity do you mean by "uncertainty"?

Comment: @Kodiologist standard deviation

Comment: Relevant:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310518/sampling-distribution-of-sample-trimmed-truncated-mean

Comment: As far as weighted mean is concerned, would it be more relevant to ask for the "weighted uncertainty of $\bar{x}$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables) tells us that for any random variables $X_i$ and constants $a_i$,

$$
\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_i a_i X_i\right) = \sum_{i}a_i^2 \operatorname{Var}(X_i) + 2\sum_{1\le i}\sum_{<j\le n}a_ia_j\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j) .
$$

Because in our case the $x_i$s are independent, their pairwise covariances are all $0$, so the nested sum on the right is just $0$. Hence,

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(\bar x) &= \left(\sum \tfrac{1}{\sigma}\right)^{-2} \operatorname{Var}\left(\sum\tfrac{x}{\sigma}\right) \\
&= \left(\sum \tfrac{1}{\sigma}\right)^{-2} \sum_i\sigma_i^{-2}\operatorname{Var}x_i \\
&= \left(\sum \tfrac{1}{\sigma}\right)^{-2} \sum_i\sigma_i^{-2}\sigma_i^2 \\
&= \left(\sum \tfrac{1}{\sigma}\right)^{-2}\sum_i 1 \\
&= n \left(\sum \tfrac{1}{\sigma}\right)^{-2} .
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but why is $\text{Var}\;x_i=1$ when the uncertainty of $x_i$ is $\sigma_i$?

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron I added an intermediate step. Clearer now?

Comment: Thanks, yes, that clears that up. One thing that I don't understand however is that this seems to ignore the "spread" in the x values. If I measure $x_1 = 100 \pm 0.01$ and $x_2=1 \pm 0.01$, then this gives $\bar x = 50.5 \pm 0.01$. What about the fact that $x_1$ is very different from $x_2$?

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron Are you sure your definition of $\bar{x}$ is correct, then? In any case, that sounds like more of a conceptual question whereas this was a formal mathematical question; you may be better off with a new post.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron Also, you told me that by "uncertainty" you meant SD, not some kind of interval uncertainty, so I answered the question under that assumption.

Comment: ...then again, each of $x_1$ and $x_2$ values could change by their uncertainty and $\bar x$ would not change much from 50.5. Is there something else that I might be looking for? (Perhaps all I wanted all along was the standard deviation across the $x$ values! Bah... but thanks for your help!!)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen OP asked for the SD of a certain quantity. I computed it. So what could be missing?